# Prove a linear transformation $\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ is uniformly continuous. Isn't boundness required?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I do know that $\left\|Lx-Ly\right\|=\left\|L(x-y)\right\|\le\left\|L\right\|\left\|x-y\right\|$ and then function is Lipschitz, but doesn't it require $||L|| $? I've been reading many sources and it wasn't unequivocal that $||L||$ must be finite. It would really help me if you could shed some light on it.

Comment: Every linear map from finite dim normed space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I do know that, but I don't think that is an answer my tutors would like.

Comment: If I recall correctly, $\Vert L\Vert$ is defined on a compact set, so it must be finite. It's been too long, so maybe someone more authoritative can shed some light.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my knowledge, I shall check this option. Thank you for reminding me the correct use of this phrase.

Comment: @Clayton that doesn't help as you might expect; *continuous* functions achieve their maximum on a compact set

Comment: Can you explain how it is hindering the process? I didn't quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute! (I assume that $\|\cdot\|$ is Euclidean norm.) Suppose $\|x\|\le 1$. Then $\|Lx\|^2=\sum_i(\sum_j L_{ij}x_j)^2$. By Cauchy-Schwarz, $(\sum_j L_{ij}x_j)^2\le \sum_j L_{ij}^2\cdot\sum_k x_k^2\le \sum_j L_{ij}^2.$ Therefore $\|L\|\le\sqrt{\sum_i \sum_j L_{ij}^2}<\infty$.

Comment: That was really silly of me to have forgotten this inequality. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Let $\dim X<\infty$ and let $\|.\|$ be the given norm on $X.$ Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator. Define, for $x\in X,$
$$\|x\|_1=\|x\|+\|T(x)\|.   $$
Then $\|.\|_1$ defines another norm on $X$ which is equivalent to the given norm $\|.\|.$  Then, $\exists\,c>0$ such that $\|T(x)\|\leq \|x\|+\|T(x)\|=\|x\|_1\leq c\|x\|, \,\forall\,x\in X.$ Therefore $T$ is continuous (uniformly).

Comment: I didn't understand how continuity is derived here. Any hint?

Comment: A linear map $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if $\exists\,c\geq 0$ such that $\|T(x)\|\leq c\|x\|$ $\forall x\in X$ and $\|T\|\leq c$

Comment: Doesn't the assertion that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|$ rather beg the question?